# Windows 2019 server image creation with driver injection

Tags: hp, deployment, drivers, windows-server-2019

I need to create a vim file win2019server image for server deployments and I'd like to know how to inject the HP drivers to the image in the easiest way and which drivers I should inject? Does HP has some driver package that can put into an image that contains all server models driver?

Appreciate all help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

HPE ProLiant servers have a built-in feature called [Intelligent Provisioning](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04465280) that installs all the required drivers for you. If you have registered the server with your HPE support account, you can download all the latest drivers and firmware as a [Service Pack for ProLiant](https://buy.hpe.com/us/en/software/infrastructure-management-software/system-server-management-software/hpe-system-server-software-management-software/service-pack-for-proliant/p/5104018).

> The Service Pack for ProLiant (SPP) is a comprehensive systems
>   software and firmware update solution, which is delivered as a single
>   ISO image. This solution uses Smart Update Manager (SUM) as the
>   deployment tool and is tested on all HPE ProLiant Gen9 and Gen10
>   servers as defined in the [Service Pack for ProLiant Server Support
>   Guide](http://www.hpe.com/servers/spp/documentation).

The service pack image is currently almost 6 GB, because it has drivers, firmware and software for all possible ProLiant combinations, but it has all the automation you need. IMO you shouldn't try and reinvent similar solutions by yourself.